# exporting java app as jar which contains other libraries

Tags: java, jar, executable, manifest.mf

I have exported my simple java application as normal jar file which contains all the source file and the dependent libraries ie jar files.
Here all the jars I have kept inside the lib folder of my application.

so these things I am able to do but when I am accessing my application as a jar file in other application then I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` because whatever libraries I have added inside the First application (which I have exported as jar contains all the dependent libraries) are not visible in runtime.

I think I need to give this information about the dependent libraries in `MANIFEST.MF` file of first application.
but I don't know whether I am thinking right or wrong.
I don't know how to write the `MANIFEST.MF` file and what would be the directory structure of the of my application if I want to keep the `MANIFEST.MF` file in my application.

Here for example I have created one jdbc application to create Connection object for that I had to add the `ojdbc14.jar` in the classpath of my application so for that I have created one lib folder inside the project root directory and I kept that `ojdbc14.jar` inside that lib folder and then I build the path.
then I exported this application as simple jar which contains that `ojdbc14.jar` also then I added this jar in my other application but while running my second application I am getting `ClassNotFoundException`.
Please Help Me On It.

Comment: are you using any dependency management tool like maven or gradle ?

Comment: One classic solution would be to use the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) if you use Maven.

Comment: no , it is a just simple java application.